# Transfering files in python 3.2 and jurko suds

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am having some troubles while I try to transfer a file using a webservice with `suds jurko` 0.5 and `Python` 3.2. It shows me that everything is ok but the file is not transferred.

It works fine if I use `Python 2.6` and `suds` (not jurko)

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: please show the code, the one that fails and the other that works

Comment: Is the same code, is about versions.

Comment: Ok, It would be much better for more investigation to show the code